# Do gang-members often hold their guns sideways?

Tags: guns

It is often portrayed in the media that members of US gangs (e.g. the [Crips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crips) and [Bloods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloods)) typically hold their guns sideways.

Here is [a stock photo illustrating how they are portrayed in the media](https://www.123rf.com/photo_13236986_image-of-young-thug-with-a-gun.html).

Is this typical?

Comment: I cannot write this as an answer because I lack proper sources, but is anything, it appears that [in this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_grip), media such as rap videos and movies affect real life just as much... so that the portrayal **makes** criminals use that gun stance to appear cool. There are a few links from the Wikipedia article, I suggest reading them.